# AngularJS remove attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that replaces my custom tag with some regular HTML.
There are some attributes that I'd like to remove. For example, given the syntax

```
<ui mybutton width="30"></mybutton>
```

my directive transforms it into

```
<div width="30" class="btn">bla bla </div>
```

I want to remove that `"width=30"` and add `style="width:{{old width value here}}"`

I've been experimenting with the compile and link function. Should I do that in the compile or in the link function?

I thought I had to do it in the compile function because I want to make a modification in the template.

See it live in http://jsfiddle.net/WptGC/2/ **WARNING: your browser might hang!**
See it live and safely http://jsfiddle.net/WptGC/3/ the code that makes everything crash is commented.

```
.directive('mybutton', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    //transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="this is my subscreen div" style="width:{{width}}"></div>',
    replace: false,
    /*scope: {
        width: '@',
        height: '@',
        x: '@',
        y: '@'
    },*/

    compile: function($tElement, $tAttrs) {
        console.log("subscreen template attrs:");
        console.log($tAttrs);
        var el = $tElement[0];
         //el.getAttribute('width');
        var stylewidth = el.getAttribute('width'); 
        el.removeAttribute('width');

         return function(scope) {
            $compile(el)(scope);
         }
    }
}
})
```

I'm just getting a strange loop (that console.log shows up a few thousand times)

Comment: The reason you were getting the loop was that you call $compile on the same element and so the compile function gets called again.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unless I'm missing some other requirement you should just be able to use isolate scope and a template like:

http://jsfiddle.net/WptGC/6/

```
app.directive('backbutton',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace:true,
    scope: {
        x: '@',
        y: '@'
    },
    template:'<button style="width: {{x}}px; height: {{y}}px">A back-button template</button>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.removeAttr('x').removeAttr('y');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: hi, yep, this is what I tried first but it preserves original attributes:

    `<div style="width: 10px; height: 0.0px" class="this is my subscreen div ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" y="0.0" x="10" width="1024.0" height="768.0" subscreen=""> </div>`

this made me think that I had to use the compile function but `return function(scope) {
            $compile(el)(scope);
         }` makes the browser crash

you can inspect the generated code in jsfiddle too

Comment: I've modified the answer.  I wouldn't spend too much time worrying about the markup though, since Angular takes liberties with it.  Is there some reason you can't have x="10.0" left in the HTML?

Comment: yep, sometimes it won't be  "x" or "y" but "width" and other attributes that can define the layout of components. the value will be the same as in css, so it won't be a pain in the neck now, but in the future it might be hard to maintain.
your answer works! thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, element.removeAttr() is the correct answer and did work for me, too.